# Avoid nested forms in table

Tags: html, forms, nested-forms

How would one create the following valid (x)HTML where the checkboxes and radiobuttons (column 3 and 4) and save button are all part of one big form, and all the delete buttons (last column) are submit buttons of their own individual forms (having a hidden field with the id of the locale), without using javascript?

```
language | region | active | default |
-----------------------------------------------
en       | GB     | [x]    | (*)     | X delete
nl       | NL     | [x]    | ( )     | X delete
nl       | BE     | [x]    | ( )     | X delete

[save]
```

Using a table, I end up having to nest forms, which of course is invalid. So, I was wondering, what other possibilities I have. Floating columns perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single form. Make use of the fact that the name-value pair of the pressed button will be sent as request parameter as well. During populating of the HTML form, dynamically inline the locale ID in the name of the button.

```
<input type="submit" name="delete_1" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_2" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_3" value="Delete" />
```

And then in the server side check if any of them have been pressed (pseudo/Java-style):

```
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    if (request.getParameter("delete_" + locale.getId()) != null) {
        // Delete button is pressed for this locale.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's a possibility indeed. But, as I also commented to @Oded, I'm trying to avoid a single point of entry action, because I'd rather have my MVC controller methods separated. But maybe I'll use this anyway after all. Because my other options are far form ideal as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different tables - one with a single form for the checkboxes, radiobuttons and save button and the second one with the delete buttons and hidden field.

Simply use CSS to reposition these next to each other.

Comment: Yeah that's a possibility indeed. Though I'm not too fond of the semantics, to be honest.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - semantically speaking, all form elements belong to one form... That's another option, though you end up submitting all the information for a single delete.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility as well. But being part of an MVC app, I'ld like forms to map to their respective actions in controllers. :-/ And without javascript I'd have to route to a single point of entry action, which I'ld rather not do.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - You could always use links instead of buttons for the delete action. And with CSS you can make them look like buttons.